# Is it possible to create a snapshot by code and save it, using pine-script?

Tags: snapshot, pine-script

I was wondering if it is possible to create and save a `snapshot`, as well as how long do the links that are created last using `pine-script`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.
See the tradingview help about [How do I take a snapshot and share it afterwards?](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000482537-how-do-i-take-a-snapshot-and-share-it-afterwards/).
It literally says `"Feel free to share a link to your snapshot at any time as it doesn't expire."`

Comment: Thanks, and Do you know another way to do it?

Comment: Maybe through the use of [webhooks](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/webhooks-for-alerts-now-available-14054/) in alerts, in combination with an external tool like [this](https://alertatron.com/docs/how-to-capture-a-chart-with-your-tradingview-alerts)

Comment: I'm thinking of using selenium, but just know the concepts never used.

Comment: OP asked about pinescript and code, not just GUI, a simple google query answers GUI at the top of the search, I'm wondering also for the programmatically answer