How to set chart link in Alert condition
I make little modification in my post.
I just want to add chart link on my alertcondition. It could be useful for those who trade with many pairs / instruments.
volEMA = ta.ema(volume, emaLength)
alertcondition(condition=volume > volEMA,
 message="Goto EURUSD")

Unfortunately I didn't find anything related. I've tried with single & double cbrakets {{ }} but it doesn't work.
Thank you in advance for the help

Read the comments on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65268752/is-it-possible-to-create-a-snapshot-by-code-and-save-it-using-pine-script
